# JQuery Ajax Post results in 500 Internal Server Error (using Laravel 5.1)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to update or insert in my database table(user_shows) whenever i click a link without going to another page. So, I used ajax and below is my code:

```
    $("#fave").click(function(){
     var url = $(this).attr("data-link");

     var data = {
        _token: $(this).data('token'),
        id: $(this).attr("name")
     };

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "/addFavorites",
        type:"post",
        data: data,
        success:function(data){
            alert(data);
        },error:function(){ 
            alert("error!!!!");
        }
    }); //end of ajax
});
    </script>
```

For the html:

```
<a id="fave" name="{{ $query[0]->tvSeriesID }}" href="#" data-link="{{  url('/addFavorites') }}" data-token="{{ csrf_token() }}" title="Mark this TV show a favorite!"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> Favorites</a>
```

For the routes:

```
Route::post('/addFavorites', function() {
   $id = Input::get('id');

   $data = $id;
   return $data;
});
```

Output: data fetch is correct
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oC1le.png)

But when I put some codes in my routes I get POST http://localhost:8000/addFavorites 500 (Internal Server Error)

Here is my new routes code

```
Route::post('/addFavorites', function() {
$id = Input::get('id');

$query = DB::table('user_shows')
            ->where('tvSeriesID', '=', $id)
            ->where('userID', '=', Auth::id())
            ->get(['favorite']);

if(empty($query))
{
    //saving to DB
    $faves = new UserShow;
    $faves->tvSeriesID = $id;
    $faves->userID = Auth::id();
    $faves->favorite = 1;        
    $faves->save();

    $data = "Show is added to Favorites";
    return $data;
}   
else
{
    if($query[0]->favorite == 1) {
        $data = "Show is already in Favorites";
    }            
    else {
        UserShow::where('tvSeriesID', $id)
            ->where('userID', Auth::id())
            ->update(['favorite' => 1]);

        $data = "Show is added to Favorites";
    }
    $data = "Show is added to Favorites";    
    return $data;
}
});
```

Is my coding wrong? Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The AJAX isn't causing it, it is what you're sending which is causing the error.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: How come when I used the first route code the data that I'm sending is being fetched and when i try to add some codes it causes error? @JayBlanchard

Comment: Because whatever you're sending is not right.

Comment: Yes, is this what you're referring to?
POST http://localhost:8000/addFavorites 500 (Internal Server Error)send 
@ jquery.min.js:4n.extend.ajax 
@ jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) 
@ 78901:183n.event.dispatch 
@ jquery.min.js:3r.handle 
@ jquery.min.js:3

@JayBlanchard

Comment: Yes - check the data you're sending via AJAX. When that data hits the PHP it is causing the 500 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out why it errors. I did not include the namespace of the model that I used which is UserShow. When I added the namespace it worked!
This is the line I added *use App\UserShow;* .
Thank you so much @Jay Blanchard for your quick response.